# How to use a GitHub repository as a webpage?

Tags: github, github-pages

### Problem

I want to use a specific **GitHub Repository** to deploy a static webpage (as I've already used xxx.github.io). I use [docsify](https://docsify.js.org/#/) to deploy it. This is my related **repo**(https://github.com/djl777/note), and this is my **website**(https://djl777.github.io/note/#/) generated.

When I upload my folder, I find some trouble: my avg and font are not changed, the relative code is in https://github.com/djl777/note/blob/master/index.html:

```html
 <link rel="icon" href="/static/image/avator.jpg">

<!-- font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/font.css">
```

So I change them to:

```html
 <link rel="icon" href="/note/static/image/avator.jpg">

<!-- font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/note/static/css/font.css">
```

and it does works, but does not work in my **local port** because of the ‘note’, so this is not a good idea.

I want to know why the root directory is xxx.github.io instead of xxx.github.io/note, and how to change it.

### supplement(another problem)

Today I find another problem in https://github.com/djl777/note/blob/master/README.md.

```markdown
![test1](/static/image/avator.jpg)

![test2](/note/static/image/avator.jpg)
```

You could see my [homepage](https://djl777.github.io/note/#/) that the **test1(/static/image/avator.jpg) is ok but not test2(/note/static/image/avator.jpg)**, this disproves my previous conjecture about absolute paths, and I'm very confused as to why `index.html` behaves differently than `README.md`. Is this not a github page issue but something to do with docify?

Besides, my repo setting is:

[image]